# Why is my lua table object empty?

Tags: lua, scripting, instantiation, lua-table

I create a lua table object called Map in my Map module, and this function creates a new instance:

```
function Map:new (o)
    o = o or {
    centers = {},
    corners = {},
    edges = {}
   }
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
```

and in my island module I put in this code in the first few lines:

```
local map = require (*map module location*)
Island = map:new ()
```

and when I print the number of centers, corners, and tables, they all come out to 0.

I have separate modules for Corner:new (), Center:new (), and Edge:new ()

Why does the length of centers, corners, and edges output as 0?

Edit:

This is what I input into the centers table for example(corners and edges is similar)

```
function pointToKey(point)
    return point.x.."_"..point.y    
end

function Map:generateCenters(centers)
    local N = math.sqrt(self.SIZE)
    for xx = 1, N do
        for yy = 1, N do
            local cntr = Center:new()
            cntr.point = {x = 0.5+xx - 1, y = 0.5+yy - 1}
            centers[pointToKey(cntr.point)] = cntr
        end
    end
    return centers
end
```

The size is always a perfect square

Comment: `map:new()` returns a table with keys `corners`, etc. that point to empty tables. Why would you expect the size to be different from zero?

Comment: Are you doing `table.insert( Island.corners, Corner:new() )` before checking the number of elements in `Island.corners`?

Comment: @GoojajiGreg check it again, I see what you mean so I went a little more in depth. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with variable scope.  Firstly, in instantiating a new `Map`, the `o` that is returned should be `local`:

```
function Map:new (o)
    local o = o or { -- this should be local
        centers = {},
        corners = {},
        edges = {}
    }
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
```

When you pass a pointer to a table to `Map:generateCenters()`, there is no need to return that pointer.  The centers have been added to that table:

```
function Map:generateCenters(centers)
    local N = math.sqrt(self.SIZE)
    for xx = 1, N do
        for yy = 1, N do
            local cntr = Center:new()
            cntr.point = {x = 0.5+xx - 1, y = 0.5+yy - 1}
            centers[pointToKey(cntr.point)] = cntr    -- HERE you're adding to the table passed as an argument
        end
    end
    -- return centers --> NO NEED TO RETURN THIS
end
```

Lastly, you would do:

```
local map = require( "map" )
local island = map:new()
map:generateCenters( island.centers )
```

You are saying, "Put the centers into the table pointed to by the table value corresponding to the key called `centers` in the table called `island`".

Lastly, note that

```
local t = island.centers
print( #t )
```

will still not output the number of elements in the table `centers` because there are gaps keys (i.e. they don't go {0,1,2,3,4,..} but rather whatever string the `pointToKey()` function returns ).  To count the elements in `centers`, you could do:

```
local count = 0
for k,v in pairs( island.centers ) do
    count = count + 1
end
print( count )
```

Comment: `o` is a local because it is a parameter.

Comment: @lhf Oh, of course.  Thanks for pointing that out. From "Programming in Lua" ch. 15: "Parameters work exactly as local variables, initialized with the actual arguments given in the function call. You can call a function with a number of arguments different from its number of parameters. Lua adjusts the number of arguments to the number of parameters, as it does in a multiple assignment: Extra arguments are thrown away; extra parameters get nil."